# How to work with Rails N:M/HABTM relationships within ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Using Ruby 2.7.0 and Ruby on Rails 6.0.3.4

Okay, suppose I have two models **En** and **Em** and I want to set an N:M relationship between them. The Rails docs are a bit scarce, but they [advise the use](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) of the `create_join_table` migration method for establishing HABTM relationships. Soon enough, running `rails g migration En Em` gives me a migration file with

### The setup:

```rb
def change
  create_join_table :ens, :ems do |t|
    t.index [:en_id, :em_id]
    t.index [:em_id, :en_id]
  end
end
```

Great. I also have to signal this N:M relationship in my En and Em models, and I do so:

```rb
class En < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ems
end
```

```rb
class Em < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ens
end
```

Looking good so far, my simple test works well too:

```rb
m = Em.create

n = En.new
n.ems << m
n.save

En.find(n.id).ems # equals [em], unsurprisingly
```

### The Problem

The moment I want to do anything more fancy with ActiveRecord, say finding some En through Em through En, I run into issues:

```rb
Em.where(ens: En.where(id: En.first)) #fails
En.where(ems: Em.where(id: Em.first)) #fails
```

```
Error:
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table ems_ens in model En::HABTM_Ems.
```

Because `create_join_table` does not give me a primary key, so I have to add one myself. No problem, one more migration should do the trick, right?

```rb
def change
  add_column :ems_ens, :id, :primary_key
end
```

```rb
Error:
DRb::DRbRemoteError: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "en_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...CT "ems".* FROM "ems" WHERE "ems"."id" IN (SELECT en_id FROM...
```

If it helps, I did [quickly write a repo](https://github.com/Magmagan/join_tables_are_wonky) to replicate this behavior exactly in this post. **Surely I'm missing something obvious here, right?** I'm having similar issues with my work code, but oddly enough I'm having issues one level deeper (something like `En.where(ems: Em.where(ens: ...))`, hierarchies in relational databases are no fun).

### Additional information

Since one commenter requested, the auto-generated `schema.rb` and described tables.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_11_09_210057) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "ems", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "mane"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "ems_ens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "en_id", null: false
    t.bigint "em_id", null: false
    t.index ["em_id", "en_id"], name: "index_ems_ens_on_em_id_and_en_id"
    t.index ["en_id", "em_id"], name: "index_ems_ens_on_en_id_and_em_id"
  end

  create_table "ens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
end
```

```
                            Table "public.ems_ens"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |               Default               
--------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 en_id  | bigint |           | not null | 
 em_id  | bigint |           | not null | 
 id     | bigint |           | not null | nextval('ems_ens_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "ems_ens_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_ems_ens_on_em_id_and_en_id" btree (em_id, en_id)
    "index_ems_ens_on_en_id_and_em_id" btree (en_id, em_id)

                                          Table "public.ems"
   Column   |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |             Default             
------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------
 id         | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('ems_id_seq'::regclass)
 mane       | character varying              |           |          | 
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "ems_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

                                          Table "public.ens"
   Column   |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |             Default             
------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------
 id         | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('ens_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying              |           |          | 
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "ens_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your schema.rb and some SQL DESCRIBE statements from the underlying DB?

Comment: Hi @3DPrintScanner, I added both of those into the original question

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not joining onto the `ens` relation, and while the `where` method is smart enough to know that it needs to look for the `en_id` column, it's not smart enough to add that join onto your query. As a result, the join table isn't in the FROM clause, so the WHERE clause ends up invalid. To fix it, you can just add `joins(:ens)`.

Incorrect (note how the FROM clause is not joining onto your join table):

```
irb(main):026:0> Em.where(ens: En.where(id: En.first))
  En Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "ens".* FROM "ens" ORDER BY "ens"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Em Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "ems".* FROM "ems" WHERE "ems"."id" IN (SELECT en_id FROM "ens" WHERE "ens"."id" = $1) LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "en_id" does not exist)
LINE 1: ...CT "ems".* FROM "ems" WHERE "ems"."id" IN (SELECT en_id FROM...
```

Corrected (note how the WHERE stays the same -- only the INNER JOIN part is new):

```
irb(main):027:0> Em.joins(:ens).where(ens: En.where(id: En.first))
  En Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ens".* FROM "ens" ORDER BY "ens"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Em Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "ems".* FROM "ems" INNER JOIN "ems_ens" ON "ems_ens"."em_id" = "ems"."id" INNER JOIN "ens" ON "ens"."id" = "ems_ens"."en_id" WHERE "ems"."id" IN (SELECT en_id FROM "ens" WHERE "ens"."id" = $1) LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Em id: 1, mane: nil, created_at: "2020-11-10 03:40:07", updated_at: "2020-11-10 03:40:07">]>
```